# SQL Server 2008 R2 migration to 2016

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2016

I'm migrating my SQL Server 2008 R2 to SQL Server 2016.

As part of migration I found a few issues before migrating like "Unqualified Join(s) detected" and "data types ntext, text and image deprecated in 2016".

How to address these two issues? Or can I go ahead and migrate my databases by ignoring these issues? Any help for migration SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2016 will be helpful. Thank you!

I took databases backups and restored them in SQL Server 2016.

Answer (score 1):

These are not necessarily huge issues.

The "unqualified joins syntax" can cause performance issues and is the more serious of the two.

Basically this is the old join syntax:

```
select * from tableA, tableB where tableA.field1 = tableB.field1
```

New syntax looks like this:

```
select * from table A inner join tableB on tableA.field1 = tableB.field1
```

Your options are:

- Don't change anything and monitor performance
- Change database compatibility level to 9.0 (you will miss out on some new features and optimizations)
- Change the code to new syntax (if not feasible at least tell developers to change it as they do new development)

Second issue is just a warning that these data types may be removed in future versions of SQL server. So this one you can ignore for now, but as the change is tricky to implement (data migration, testing, code changes) you should start on it with your development team before they are actually removed in a future version of SQL.